# How to populate handpicked listview rows into one main fragment, from several other fragments

Tags: android, sql, android-fragments, android-listview

I am working on an application that basically has one *main fragment* and several *secondary fragments*. Each of the *secondary fragments* currently have a **custom listview**, where each row in each *secondary fragment* has an image, a string of text and a button to mark it as a favorite. So when when the user marks any row as favorite, the favorited rows should immediately display inside the *primary fragment* with the same custom listview format (with an image, string of text and a button).

The application is ready and working (minus the 'add and populate the favorites feature')

The rows of each custom listview look like this:

[image]

The *main fragment* is intended to immediately display all listview rows (in sequence), after the user has favorited particular listview rows from several other *secondary fragments*.

The structure of the application is like this:

[image]

After reading through similar topics, I understand that using SQL would be the right way to store and retrieve a large amount of data.

I've referred to this tutorial - [Asynchronously populating listview from SQLite database using Content Providers](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/asynchronously-populating-listview-from-sqlite-database-using-content-providers/), which has been of great help to understand a few things. But i'm finding it difficult to implement this with respect to custom list views (that include images in each row), and collecting all of the favorited items into a separate *main fragment*.

With reference to the link above and the mentioned requirements, how can I implement this feature into the application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the observer pattern? You basically just have to register your main fragment as an observer to listen to added favourists from your other fragments.

You register your fragments 1,2,3....n inside a central component like the parent activity
`reg = ((ObserverRegistryDispatcher) Fragment.getActivity()).registerAsSubject(Fragment.this, EventId.ADD_FAVOURITE);`

Then you can use it to dispatch events

`reg.notifyObservers(EventId.ADD_FAVOURITE, favouriteEntity);`

You basically do the equivalent thing for your MainFragment, but register it as an observer and get the event inside the appropriate callback method

`((ObserverRegistryDispatcher) Fragment.getActivity()).registerAsObserver(MainFragment.this.getObserverImpl(), EventId.ADD_FAVOURITE);`

`public void onEventOccurred(EventId eventId, Object... arguments) { if (EventId.ADD_FAVOURITE.equals.(eventId)) { // add entity in favourite list }`